# Dynamically eager-loading STI classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading, single-table-inheritance

**Scenario:** I have a number of STI models in my Rails 3.2 app. At times, I use parent classes to query the databases for child classes, as shown below:

```
class ParentObject < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ChildObject < ParentObject
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parent_objects
end

> User.find(1).parent_objects
 => [#<ParentObject ...>, #<ChildObject ...>]
```

If I inspect the generated SQL query, that's what I (expectedly) see:

```
WHERE "parent_objects"."type" IN ('ParentObject', 'ChildObject')
```

**Problem:** when in development environment, classes are dynamically reloaded when there's changes. If I change something on `ParentObject` and don't restart the Rails console, that's what I get instead:

```
> User.find(1).parent_classes
 => [#<ParentObject ...>]
```

Inspecting the generated SQL:

```
WHERE "parent_objects"."type" IN ('ParentObject')
```

But:

```
> ChildObject
 => ChildObject(...)
> User.find(1).parent_objects
 => [#<ParentObject ...>, #<ChildObject ...>]
```

**Question:** where in my Rails app can I write a small piece of code that will reload any STI models on every web server request?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution...:

```
# in development.rb
ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
  Rails.application.eager_load!
end
```

Comment: in production, the classes are cached at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a filter on ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :reload_sti_classes if Rails.env.development?

  def reload_sti_classes
    [ParentObject, ChildObject]
  end
end
```

It doesn't seem right to me though.

Comment: did you found a better solution?

Comment: Not really, I didn't pursue it much.